# Subnet and IP address ANDing trailing 0's

Tags: powershell, binary, ipv4, subnet

So I have a script that is ANDing an IPv4 address and a subnet address. Not checking to see if it is a valid input (which I should add), it converts the input to binary.

```
if ($readInput -match "y"){
    $readIP = read-host "Please input an IPv4 address to be ANDed " 

    # need to add subnet mask later. 
    $readSub = read-host "Please input the Subnet Mask "


    #need to delimite '.'
    #$readIP.split "."
    #$readSub.split "."

    #need to join them

    #convert IPv4 address to binary, period seperated at each octet. (input ip, base 2)
    $binIP = [convert]::ToString($readIP,2)
    write-host "$binIP" -backgroundcolor "white" -foregroundcolor "black"
    ## need to have two 32 element array that compares each 1 and 0. loop through each one with a counter and compare them with
    ## conditional if statements

    #conditional statements for /cider notion to equal a binary number (mask, base 2)
    $binSub = [convert]::ToString($readSub,2)
    write-host "$binSub" -backgroundcolor "white" -foregroundcolor "black"
}
```

The input is:

```
19216823
2552552550
```

The output is:

```
1001001010011100110110111
10011000001001001101110001100110
```

Do I have to add 7 trailing 0's at the end of the IP address in order to perform proper ANDing?

Comment: Last week I posted this https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/349680/28443 musing about encodings and binary. You're someone else who possibly has the same misunderstanding as the question poster. "*#convert IPv4 address to binary;    $binIP = [convert]::ToString($readIP,2)*" - that is what it's doing, but at completely the wrong level, you're not converting "to binary" in the way IPs and Subnets work, you're converting to "a string of ascii characters representing binary with ones and zeros and using 8x more space"

Comment: Those are not the correct decimal representations of `192.168.2.3` and `255.255.255.0`

Comment: Unless you deliberately want to do it at this level for some reason, what you need is 32-*bit* arrays, 4 bytes, no separate octets, and bit manipulating `-band`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Hmm Interesting read.  I never thought about binary in that sense. What would you suggest?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen correct, that's why the delimiter code is in there then my plan is to join them at the end.

Comment: my plan was to store the data into a 32 bit array and do a comparison at each subscript. 01, 10, 00, 11. Then formulate it into a new 32bit string.

Comment: @schnipdip That's my point, that would give you the wrong result. In any case, @TessellatingHeckler is right, you need to ditch using strings for network calculations, it's not as straightforward as you seem to intuit. Use the `[System.Net.IPAddress]` class instead

Comment: Ahhh, okay @MathiasR.Jessen I understand what you're saying now. Bill Stewart (below) wrote a great example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's usually easier to use the `[IPAddress]` class. Example:

```
$ip = [IPAddress] "192.168.32.76"
$networkMask = [IPAddress] "255.255.255.0"
$networkID = [IPAddress] ($ip.Address -band $networkMask.Address)
$networkID.IPAddressToString  # outputs "192.168.32.0"
```

If you want to count the bits in a network mask string, you can use a function like this:

```
function ConvertTo-IPv4MaskBits {
  param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String] $MaskString
  )
  $mask = ([IPAddress] $MaskString).Address
  for ( $bitCount = 0; $mask -ne 0; $bitCount++ ) {
    $mask = $mask -band ($mask - 1)
  }
  $bitCount
}
```

This function assumes a correctly formed network mask ID.

A full write-up and some more functions are available in an article I wrote a while back:

[IT Pro Today - Working with IPv4 Addresses in PowerShell](https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/working-ipv4-addresses-powershell)

Comment: wuhhhh you just blew my mind. I had no idea there was an IPaddress class. I will read that link, thank you for the feedback!

Comment: As I am reading your article, you are blowing my mind Bill. I am a beginner of PowerShell, so this is amazing information. I am still trying to grasp the concept of Functions in Powershell and keeping more to a simplistic layout. You have opened my eyes and I need to learn more about classes and functions.

Comment: Great, glad it is helpful/useful.

Comment: Bill, this is amazing! I am having a ton of fun with this! I made a graph and am doing comparisons of networks addresses to determine if two addresses are in the same network or not. For easy troubleshooting.